# Selenium Webdriver: Issues Clicking a button within dropdown <li>

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having an issue with clicking a button using Selenium Webdriver. I have tried using a wait to no avail, it's possible I'm not doing it correctly though as I'm new to this. I am also receiving an error about global driver issues but again, I'm not doing this right and haven't been able to find the correct way to go about this.

The Error I'm getting:

```
ERROR: test_categorySelect (__main__.TitleTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "auto2.py", line 24, in test_categorySelect
    category = self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[]@id='menu-item-34']/a")))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
TimeoutException: Message: 
Screenshot: available via screen


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 15.817s
```

Here is the demo site:

http://store.demoqa.com

The code for the area I'm trying to click is here:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-34" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpsc_product_category menu-item-34">
    <span class="before">&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="http://store.demoqa.com/products-page/product-category/accessories/">
        <span></span>
        Accessories
    </a>
</li>
```

Here is my current code:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class TitleTest(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    # self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    self.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

def test_title(self):
    self.driver.get("http://store.demoqa.com")
    self.assertIn("STORE", self.driver.title)
    print "================================================================"
    print "==== Successful Title Match ===="
    print "================================================================"

def test_categorySelect(self):
    category = self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[]@id='menu-item-34']/a")))
    ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(category).click().perform()
    print "================================================================"
    print "==== Successful Accessories Button Clicked ===="
    print "================================================================"


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Try using self.driver instead of just driver to avoid the global driver issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that it times out waiting for the submenu to be visible, but there's no action performed before the call to wait.until.

You need to mouse over the 'Product Category' with ActionChains and then click the specific category.

```
def test_categorySelect(self):
    self.driver.get("http://store.demoqa.com")
    product_category = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li[id='menu-item-33']")
    category = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li[id='menu-item-34']")
    ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(product_category).click(category).perform()
```

Comment: Am I missing the wait in there from what you wrote? I added the code that you gave me and I'm still getting the "element not visible" message. I'm trying to figure out where to add the wait back in.

Comment: :( I tested the above function with self.driver = webdriver.Chrome() and it worked without the wait.

Comment: If you wanted to add a wait in between you could try doing the ActionChain in steps as mentioned here http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains  . You could put the wait in between the call to move_to_element() and click()

Comment: You're 100% right! I may ditch running Phantom to test, it seems to be unnecessary. Chrome worked perfectly, thank you and I will look into the link you posted when using waits.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked, if it solved your issue could you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra closing bracket **]**, change your locator to this : `"//li[@id='menu-item-34']/a"`

Comment: Thanks Prateek, I adjusted.